# WatchKit how to create custom Localizable.strings file?

Tags: ios, localization, watchkit

I created for the interface.storyboard at the WatchKit App the following files, by activating Localisation:

[image]

In the IOS App I also have the Localisable.strings files where I put all my custom words for the specific language (but I can not remember how I created it or if it was created automatically):

[image]

How can I create the **Localizable.strings** file at the WatchKit App and tell the WatchKit App to use that file?

At the moment

```
myLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"msgMylabel", @"");
```

displays msgMylabel and not the content of msgMylabel

Interface.strings (English)
"msgMylabel" = "my label";

Interface.strings (German)
"msgMylabel" = "mein Label";

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer:

I had to add the **WatchKit Extension** (not WatchKit App) as Target Membership for *Localizable.strings (English)* and *Localizable.strings (German)*.